# How implement user matching algorithm into Django app

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin

I'm creating a `Django` app that allows `users to register` as either a "`mentor`" or "`mentee`". Each user has some information stored in the **User** that is common across all accounts, while mentors/mentees have a second table (one-to-one) **MentorProfile/MenteeProfile** with areas of expertise/interest.

The goal is to create a mechanism by which a mentor is assigned to a mentee after running a matching algorithm (such as stable relationship). I have working registration/edit features, however am stuck on how to begin implementing the match.

Is there a way to introduce a button into the Django admin panel that, when clicked:

- Pulls the necessary information from the Django app
- Makes the Mentor/Mentee matches and assignments
- Updates the MentorProfile and MenteeProfile tables with these matches

For what it's worth, we have a working python script that pulls the necessary information from a csv that can make the mentor/mentee relationship assignment. We are simply unsure on how to implement this logic into our app.

EDIT:
Just a general view of my models. Additionally, the User class has the default user attributes (username, firstname, lastname, email, etc.)

Here is my **blog/models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  is_mentor = models.BooleanField('Mentor', default=False)
  is_mentee = models.BooleanField('Mentee', default=False)


class MenteeProfile(models.Model):
CAREER_CHOICES = [
    ('Doctor', 'Doctor'),
    ('Teacher', 'Teacher'),
    ('Engineer', 'Engineer'),
    ('Scientist', 'Scientist'),
    ('Biologist', 'Biologist'),
    ('Business', 'Business')
]
user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
career_interest1 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Doctor', choices=CAREER_CHOICES)
career_interest2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Doctor', choices=CAREER_CHOICES)
career_interest3 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Doctor', choices=CAREER_CHOICES)

class MentorProfile(models.Model):
user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
AREA_OF_EXPERTISE = [
    ('Doctor', 'Doctor'),
    ('Teacher', 'Teacher'),
    ('Engineer', 'Engineer'),
    ('Scientist', 'Scientist'),
    ('Biologist', 'Biologist'),
    ('Business', 'Business')
    ('--', '--')    ]
career_expertise1 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='--', choices=AREA_OF_EXPERTISE)
career_expertise2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='--', choices=AREA_OF_EXPERTISE)
career_expertise3 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='--', choices=AREA_OF_EXPERTISE)
career_expertise4 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='--', choices=AREA_OF_EXPERTISE)
career_expertise5 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='--', choices=AREA_OF_EXPERTISE)
career_expertise6 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='--', choices=AREA_OF_EXPERTISE)
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Thanks!

Every Help Will Be Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls):

> In admin.py file:

```
class MentorProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #define your list display or fieldsets
     ....
     ....

     #now need to define urls for custom button in admin template file
     def get_urls(self):
        """
        generate urls for methods. and attach with admin url
        :param self:
        """
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^match-mentee/$', self.match_mentee),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

        def match_mentee(self, request):
        """
        here you put the matching logic
        """
        ....
        ....
        self.message_user(request, "mentor has been assigned to mentee")
        return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
```

For the addition of a custom button in admin template, there are limits so far as I remember when I needed to customise it in django 1.8. So only limited part of admin template can be customised. I would like you to refer the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) to explore for customisation.

Also, put the url in in button's `href` to make button working in template.

Comment: Thank you! This is something quite like what I'm looking for. But additionally, I am running into a wall defining what you call the "match_mentee" logic. If it would help I could share my python script that matches our students (outside of the django framework) as a jumping off point to implement this into my app.

Comment: If it would help you, upvote and mark as accepted answer. Let me know if you are stuck again. :)